# Swift 3.0 How to add a child on a parent in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a new child for instance games; and then data with games that the user have for instance "bought"... The thing is that the precondition is that the user is signed in, I've managed to store the data for when a user is logged in... So now I want to create a new child under this specific user and save some data for this which I just can't get to work.

```
Database.database().reference().child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Games").updateChildValues(["game" : downloadURL])
```

[image]

Under users I would like to create a new child called Games and then add data to this child. In this example it should below the -KrC.... (the user)

Comment: In the future, please post your Firebase structure as text, no images or links. You can get your structure from the Firebase Console->Export JSON and copy and paste it from that file

Comment: The problem is your code. You forgot to include "Users/" in your path.

Comment: What do you mean J. Doe ? Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid should point to the user? and then creating a node (child) should do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is that you want to add another child node?

Assume the user is authenticated and their uid is uid_0

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var ref: DatabaseReference!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let thisUsersGamesRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("Games")

        let gameRef0 = thisUsersGamesRef.childByAutoId().child("game_url")
        gameRef0.setValue("http://www...")

        let gameRef1 = thisUsersGamesRef.childByAutoId().child("game_url")
        gameRef1.setValue("http://www..")
}
```

will give

```
users
 uid_0
   email: ....
   Games:
     -Yuhu98js9d
        game_url: "http://www..."
     -H89j90k0s0
        game_url: "http://www..."
```

Comment: Yes, but It shouldn't  take -KrCv as parameter? it should take the one thats logged in? so that its generic

Comment: Updated to obtain the current users uid

Comment: Yes exactly! but could you elaborate about this part; 
let ref = self.ref.child("users").child(uid).child("Games")
 I need to save it to the database how do I declare the uid and ref variable??? according to firebase..

Comment: It's at the top - first line of code *let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid*. The ref comes from your database. I'll throw some more code in. Most of that is covered in the Firebase [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: I tried it by doing it;

   let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("Games")
                    ref.updateChildValues(["image" : downloadURL])

didn't work tho..

It just created a new user parent and then added new nodes to it...

Comment: Correct. That code won't work. Use the code in my question as it will save you a lot of typing in the long run. Establish self.ref early in the class, and then from there on anytime you want to access a reference you can use let someRef = self.ref.child("users") or self.ref.child("posts") etc. Much shorter.

Comment: I used the code in your question, but it just recreates the User parent, and not adding a new node to the parent with the game data as additional nodes under this.. It seems like it can't allocate the reference of the user ui'd thats already been logged in with...

Comment: Ok a little stupid mistake its case sensitive with (users and Users) So now it creates a new node inside of users, but still not recognizing the uid of the (randomly created user)...

so its like Users
                  - IYisds3s
                     - Email xa
                  - IY8i9dsd
                     - Games

instead of 
                   - IYisds3s
                     - Email
                     - Games

Comment: Ok. I probably provided too much info in my answer. I totally re-wrote it for clarity. Also, I want to retract my statement that the code in your above comment won't work. It actually does work.

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it, I just tried your code, and It looks great but It still dosen't do it under the already existing user (uid). It just recreated a new parent and then do the node part.. :I

Comment: Then you have a typo! I am running the code and it definitely creates the Games node under the currently authenticated user. And.. each time I run the code, it creates two more games nodes under the Games parent node for the user. There's nothing in that code that would re-create anything.

Comment: Im not sure, dosen't work for me :I.. Im not sure if this has something to do with that im crossing different view controllers signup -> add game (press a button) or what it is... I tried different attempts but just recreates a new parent under Users but not under the uid(user) :I

Comment: If it's creating a new parent under Users that would mean each time you run it, it's under a different user uid, right?   Users/uid_x then run it again, Users/uid_y etc. That's the only way it would happen. Try adding a *print(uid!)* right after you *let uid =* so you can verify the uid is the same value each time.

Comment: Exactly thats what I mean, it creates a new (uid) under Users, it apparently changes after doing the code....? How do I prevent this and always send the same uid I use when I first sign up? >.< I thought that the Auth.auth(uid) part make sure to use the same user thats been Authed recently?? and keeps that uid....

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I constructed my signup Kinda wrong, and created a new uid, but didn't inherit the same uid from Auth when adding the user to the database !! Thanks a lot for the help :-)